# Recompose is canceled

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

In the documentation of jetpack UI compose they mention the recompositing state as below:

> When recomposition is canceled, Compose discards the UI tree from the
> recomposition.  If you have any side-effects that depend on the UI
> being displayed, **the side-effect will be applied even if composition
> is canceled. This can lead to inconsistent app state.**

is inconsistent state means the composable widget will be shown that is what side effect means?

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you mean in your question, but the above states that when recomposition is cancelled, any side effects you may have in your composable will still render. This might cause your UI to be inconsistent. If you want to read more about side effects, you can do so [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).